# Nuxt fresh install contains warning of dependency on Vite

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I am installing a fresh Nuxt 3.9.3 app and I am getting the following warnings. My devtools are not working. I am on MacOS.

```
Projects % npx nuxi init nuxt-3

✔ Which package manager would you like to use?
yarn
◐ Installing dependencies...                                                                                                                             7:54:54 PM
yarn install v1.22.21
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
warning vscode-languageclient@7.0.0: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "nuxt > @nuxt/devtools@1.0.8" has unmet peer dependency "vite@*".
warning "nuxt > @nuxt/devtools > vite-plugin-vue-inspector@4.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "vite@^3.0.0-0 || ^4.0.0-0 || ^5.0.0-0".
warning "nuxt > @nuxt/devtools > vite-plugin-inspect@0.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "vite@^3.1.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0-0".
warning "nuxt > @nuxt/devtools > @nuxt/devtools-kit@1.0.8" has unmet peer dependency "vite@*".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
$ nuxt prepare
✔ Types generated in .nuxt                                                                                                                              7:55:39 PM
✨  Done in 44.58s.
✔ Installation completed.                                                                                                                               7:55:39 PM
```